# Problem in mounting hard disks

Tags: mount

I previously had Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04(32 bit) on my system.I installed Ubuntu 14.04(64 bit) replacing the 32 bit Ubuntu,But it also Removed Windows 10.Now,the problem is,My hard disk partitions are not mounting posing an error:

```
Error mounting /dev/sda5 at /media/pavan/DSK1_VOL2: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda5" "/media/pavan/DSK1_VOL2"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda5': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I don't have windows 10 on my computer.What do i do?

Comment: `sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda5` -- see what happens

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Thank you..It worked..My 2 partitions mounted ...But my c drive is not mounting...

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to remove Windows 10 (and all its data) you could run `gparted` and tell it to format `/dev/sda5` (really, really make sure this is the right partition) as `ext4`, and when it's finished, you will have an empty `ext4` partition, not a corrupted, unmountble (unless you "`resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting)`" NTFS partition.